# Get pdf meta data like sheet dimensions using javascript client side

Tags: javascript, pdf, metadata

We are trying to develop a remote printer service for our users using web technologies like PHP, MySQL, HTML, JS, CSS: authenticated users can upload their files and these files are plotted by our HP plotter (an old Designjet model). The solution is almost done... We miss a piece about client side.
Ore rule is that users can only upload PDF files. The main program users use to create their works is Autocad but can also use ArchiCad, Photoshop, Ms Project and others.
By default Autocad and the majority of the other programs export PDF @300dpi. 
Before an user can upload his file we wish to get some infos about this file like:
dpi (our plotter can have problems printing pdf files having a resolution greater than 150dpi)
number of pages (users can print up to 5 sheets a day)
page dimensions (users can print up to 3 meters for single print)
Probably it's more simple to get these infos server side but I wish to avoid that our users can wasting time waiting for a big size upload file and after receive a messege telling that the file can't be printed!
So, my question is: how can we get these infos about a pdf file client side using javascript? Could PDFjs be useful for our goal? We were unable to find out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it sounds hard, but this is close to off-topic like "requesting a tool suggestion".  Are you talking about pixel graphics being exported? PDF generally is a vector format and a "dpi" value might be misleading here? Document type and dimensions maybe could be done client-side at the cost of loading the doc in the browser. The number of sheets printed per day you probably don't want to let the browser determine, if users find out they use a different computer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay. Users must have an account for using the service so they first have to login and after they can send files: in this manner is easy to track the number of pages. About resolution, instead, how we can determine at which dpi a pdf was exported? For our pourposes is enough that users export @150dpi from their programs (e.g. Autocad) because the pdf exported in this way is ok. We're sorry if our message could be considered off topic but a solution for our problem could be useful for other developes.